# Zeros of Weierstrass p function

Tags: elliptic-functions

I would like to know where the zeros of the $\wp$ function lie in terms of its periods. I know that we can locate the zeros of its derivative, $\wp'$, but I can't figure how to locate the roots of the original function. Any help?

Comment: You may see here:http://people.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/zagier/files/doi/10.1007/BF01453974/fulltext.pdf

Comment: They are not trivial ones, as the zeros of $\wp'$. In general, the zeros will be integrals.